# How to get total all item of child locations to parent location

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have new created parent location and created many child locations into new parent location. When I add items to child location but parent location have amount is 0. I would like to get all amount item of child to parent location

`Ex. page Stock by Location in Warehouse
parent: Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock   but item = 0 (i want result is 14) 
child : Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock / Shelf 1   item = 3 
child : Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock / Shelf 2    item = 1 
child : Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock / Shelf 3    item = 10`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code you tried so far?

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo I write not code but I do all data in OpenERP View. I create AA location is parent location and A1 is child location, And then I delivered 5 of product from stock location to my A1 location(internal). The amount of item add to A1 location already but parent AA location have amount is zero, it uncounted item of child location to parent AA location. I would like amount of parent

Comment: then you need to write code in order to have an extra field into location that sums up children items recursively

Comment: Normal case, when I have delivery or incoming product to 'location Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock / Shelf 1' of OpenERP then location 'Physical Locations / Your Company / Stock' is parent, it will get sums amount of child items auto. but my created location can't do it. Will I write code sums?